# Issue with MUI AppBar and SideBar(MUI Drawer)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, tailwind-css, drawer, appbar

Anyone please help to resolve this MUI and Tailwind issue as I'm facing below for adjusting the AppBar and MUI Menu Drawer.

[In this image siderbar is hidded in the names and you can see the Header(MUI Appbar is hidden inside the Drawer on left side)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfTOj.png)
[In this image also same the menu expanded but still the Header(AppBar is still hidden behind the Drawer)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXDDh.png)

From the First images: In this image siderbar is hidded in the names and you can see the Header(MUI Appbar is hidden inside the Drawer on left side.

From the Second Image: In this image also same the menu expanded but still the Header(AppBar is still hidden behind the Drawer

I need to the Header and Drawer should be display like inline but I have tried with many ways using Tailwind to madify the MUI structure but didn't get result. Could someone help on this.

Header.tsx

```
<AppBar className="w-[85%] bg-white rounded-lg m-2">
    <Toolbar></Toolbar>
 </AppBar>
```

```
 <Drawer variant="permanent" open={open}>
      <DrawerHeader>
        <IconButton className="h-14 w-14 my-0" onClick={handleDrawerOpen}>
          Logo
        </IconButton>
      </DrawerHeader>
      <List>
        {isSuccess &&
          menuData &&
          menuData.data &&
          menuData.data.menu.map((item: { name: string }, index: number) => {
            return (
              <ListItem key={index}>
                <ListItemButton>
                  <ListItemText primary={item.name} />
                </ListItemButton>
              </ListItem>
            );
          })}
</List
```

I need final image look like the below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcHjt.png)